# How to overcome memory issues in ADOconnection in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have following code from where i am getting error when trying to connect to a database in sql server.

```
ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    // build a connection string; for more information, search for ADO
    // connection string on the Internet
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +
      'Data Source='+ 'TestServer' + ';' +
    //  'Initial Catalog='+ DBPage.Values[1] + ';' +
    // 'Integrated Security=SSPI;';
     'User Id='+ 'sa' + ';' +
      'Password='+ 'Password1' + ';';
    // open the connection by the assigned ConnectionString
    ADOConnection.Open;
```

//I am getting below error when the connection happens

[image]

Comment: i have 4 ADOconnection variables which are of variant datatype. only one of them showing errors other are not showing error

Comment: i am using unicode version of inno setup

Comment: Forget all those connections and your whole script. Start a new script and try to connect just with this one connection and only with the code you've posted. And simulate it with the exact values that you wrote in your `DBPage`. Will that work ? Also, is that **really** the only script code that you execute ? I mean is this error thrown when you call `Open` on your connection object, **not by executing some query** ? Btw. please include all the information in the question. It's unecessarily time consuming to collect a description of your problem from comments.

Comment: Have you tried to narrow the problem you observe as I suggested ? Have you localized the exact place where the exception is raised ? Sorry for repeating myself, but all the articles I've seen so far describes that this is an ADO issue which occurs when fetching records, not when opening connection. Hence I still think it's not related to this code nor count of the connection objects.